# How to translate data you get from firebase in android?*Multi-language supported

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multilingual

I'm working on an application in Android Studio. I managed to connect my app to `firebase`, from which I'm getting some images and descriptions in English. As I would like my app to support multiple languages, is there any way to translate this data from the database into some other language in my Android app?

I know how that works with static data, using `strings.xml`, but I'm just wondering can I do it if data is loaded from `firebase`?

EDIT ***

I'm extracting images and their descriptions from firebase, using RecyclerView and CardView. In order to to that I use :

1. Image class (POJO class)
2. Image adapter class

   ```
   public  class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder> {
       ArrayList<Image> mImages;

       public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<Image> mAds)
       {
           this.mImages = mAds;
       }

       @Override
       public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
           return new ImageViewHolder(inflatedView);
       }

       public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
           final Image image = mImages.get(position);
           holder.bindAd(image);
           holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   //Open New Activity show details about advertisment
                   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ImageDetails.class);
                   intent.putExtra("ad",image);

                   view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return mImages.size();
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Image view holder class:

   ```
   public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       private ImageView mAdImage;
       private TextView mAdName;

       public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           mAdImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_image);
           mAdName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_name);
       }

       public void bindAd(Image ad) {
           mAdName.setText(ad.name);
           Glide.with(mAdImage.getContext()).load(ad.image1).into(mAdImage);
       }
   }
   ```
4. ImageDetails class (when image clicked, it opens with its description)

   ```
   public class ImageDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.image_details);
           // TO DO
           //Ad ad = (Ad) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ad");
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAdDetails);
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAdDetails);
           TextView textDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionAdDetails);

           if (getIntent().hasExtra("ad")) {
               Image ad = (Image) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ad");
               textView.setText(ad.name);
               textDesc.setText(ad.AdDescription);
               Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(ad.image1).into(imageView);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why You post the question for get ideas ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dzana, I think firebase itself would give you translated data. Or you have to add google translation jar and then you can. @Dzana

Comment: What data do you get from Firebase that needs translation? Please post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/9F3Tio_gGNg

Comment: @AjayPandya, probably because I'm beginner! This is the first time I'm working with Android, and I made a huge progress, and want to get as much knowledge as I can. If this question bothers anyone, it will be deleted by stackoverflow anyhow :)

Comment: @DzanaBasic its okay, cmon guys dont fight and lets solve the problem. Thats good you did a good work I think. Lets make it solve okay.

Comment: @PratikDasa I posted my code, hope It will help somebody who is doing similar things :) I can add screenshots as well

Comment: ya its okay @DzanaBasic let me check and will try to do needfull. You can contact me on my email id as well for any concern.

Comment: @DzanaBasic You can use google translation for this, it will work for you.

Comment: @PratikDasa, I really don't understand how that works :/ If my phone is set to French language, and I launch my app, my data in firebase is in English, how will it translate automatically to French :/

Comment: Are you able to communicate via gmail? Let me explain you. @DzanaBasic

Comment: Just Do One Thing Get Locale Of Your Phone Than When Your App Starts Set Data As Per Phone Current Locale For Your DataBase You Have To Manage All Field With Appropriate Translation

Answer (score 0):

the first idea that comes to my mind is to duplicate the node with descriptions in the database for other language versions.
Let's say you a have a node "image_descriptions" and its child nodes are (img1_description, img2_description, and so on).
Imagine you need to translate the descriptions to Spanish and use them when Spanish locale is set in your app config.

1. Create a node in the database with name "image_descriptions_spanish"
2. fill this node with the same child nodes, but with value descriptions now in Spanish
3. Extract a string resource from "image_descriptions", create a new locale and set the spanish tranlation of "image_descriptions" to "image_descriptions_spanish"

So, the line where you instantiate a DB Ref to image_descriptions node will be like:

```
DatabaseReference descriptionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getString(R.string.image_description)
```

The relevant language will be displayed automatically depending on the locale selected.